# GNOME Ubuntu 15.04 lock screen not present

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.04

A few days ago I had a trouble in my starting service 219.To repair it I accidentally installed unity desktop .Then I was not able to login. Then I installed gnome desktop. Now everything works fine but when I close my laptop, It is not going to sleep mode and when I open it the desktop appears right away. And also the cursor is not changing. It has been white ever since. I tried to change it in tweak tools but I was not able to change it. Please help me.

Comment: In regards to your comment on your question regarding missing folders in 16.04 (which you deleted prior to my having a chance to respond): Bad sectors indicate that the magnetic field which holds your data on the drive in question is failing. You should backup all critical data on the drive in question immediately and replace it as soon as possible. My thanks to @Rinzwind for finding your username for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently. It seems that ubuntu-gnome doesn't show the lock screen when using lightdm. I suggest that you switch to GDM . The lock screen should be available again. You can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

Hope this help!

itSp4x

Comment: @Saikumar - If this answer works for you make sure you accept (and perhaps upvote) it :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!